# Xvfb stuck at "built-in extension GLX" on Amazon Linux

Tags: rhel, amazon-ec2, xvfb

I started to use AWS EC2 with Amazon Linux a few days ago.
I am running java with selenium webdriver over firefox to get some data from websites, and it works well when running on my windows computer.

I manage to connect to my AWS instance with ssh -X and I can run selenium graphically. But I want to do it with an headless firefox aswell. I saw that it is possible to start an headless firefox if Xvfb is running.

So I installed Xvfb with : `sudo yum install Xvfb` and runned it with `Xvfb` and it showed me many `Initializing built-in extension` messages.

But when it comes to `Initializing built-in extension GLX` it just seems to stop and do nothing until I press Ctrl-C.

Any idea ? I'm starting with Linux, so it may be a basic mistake I made.

Comment: Ok, as I was thinking, it was a basic problem.
Xvfb was working, that's just that it doesn't give you the hand back.
I had to run it like this : 

    "Xvfb :1 &"
    "export DISPLAY=:1 &"

I can use the "ps" command to see that Xvfb is running